# Is opening SMTP port with default Sendmail config safe?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, smtp, sendmail

My self-hosted web app (Ubuntu VPS) needs the ability to send noreply@ notifications to users when something goes wrong. I don't really need the ability to receive emails but I would like to comply with internet standards and enable such inboxes as postmaster@, abuse@, etc (I'm mostly worried about otherwise triggering anti-spam protection as my notifications are sent when immediate user intervention is required).

To achieve the above goal I have installed Sendmail, configured some DNS records and opened Sendmail to listen on ports 25 and 587 publically (I believe that is required to receive external emails). I can now send and receive emails perfectly fine, however, I'm worried about security.

As my SMTP server is wide open to the public and I haven't configured any authentication does this mean that some malicious actor could freely send emails on behalf of my service? Is there an option to allow sending emails only from localhost and is this even a secure check (can't the external sender IP-address be spoofed to appear as localhost)?

Comment: `noreply` is not how email works. You are not bound to *receive* responses in the same places you *send* messages out, though.

Comment: @anx, could you please elaborate on your comment? Do you mean that sending emails from noreply@somedomain.com is a bad practice or are you talking about some technical aspect of email?

Comment: Postfix may be a better choice as SMTP server unless you have sendmail experience.

Comment: Incoming mail does NOT need to be handled by the same mail server as outgoing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're very probably running a wide-open mail server and will shortly become a spam source if you aren't one already. You do not need to be able to receive email in order to send it. In your situation, I would advise closing up ports 25 and 587, and don't worry about retrieving the postmaster@ or abuse@ email there.

What anx was implying in his comment above is that your sending mail server doesn't have to be your receiving mail server. If you feel you ought to retrieve the administrative emails, you can set up a Google redirect and use that to retrieve the admin mails. If you want those to come into your new server, you should really set up authentication, before you open up the ports.

Comment: This is outdated.

Since 1998,
Sendmail by default do not allow relaying (that is, accepting mail from outside your domain and sending it to another host outside your domain)

Answer (score 0):

Outgoing SMTP is not a problem. Incoming could be.

Make sure in your sendmail config that you are not an open relay.

You could run this to prevent an open relay

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "FEATURE(`relay_hosts_only')dnl" >> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'
sudo m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
sudo systemctl restart sendmail
```

I would also recommend to integrate sendmail with spamassian

```
#!/bin/bash

# Update system packages
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y

# Install necessary packages
sudo apt install -y  spamassassin spamc

# Start SpamAssassin
sudo systemctl start spamassassin
sudo systemctl enable spamassassin

# Configure Sendmail for SpamAssassin
sudo sh -c 'echo "dnl # Uncomment the line below to enable the SpamAssassin Milter" >> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'
sudo sh -c 'echo "INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(\`spamassassin', \`S=local:/var/run/spamass-milter.sock, F=, T=C:15m;S:4m;R:4m;E:10m')dnl" >> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'
sudo sh -c 'echo "dnl # Define Milter macros" >> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'
sudo sh -c 'echo "define(\`confMILTER_MACROS_CONNECT', \`j, _, {daemon_name}, {if_name}, {if_addr}')dnl" >> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'
sudo sh -c 'echo "define(\`confMILTER_MACROS_HELO', \`{verify}, {cert_subject}')dnl" >> /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'

# Rebuild Sendmail configuration
sudo m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
sudo systemctl restart sendmail



echo "Script execution complete."
```

Comment: As far as I understand the relay rules are configured inside `/etc/mail/access`. [Here's mine](https://pastebin.com/UJLrUYnw) with comments removed. Am I correct in understanding that only emails from `localhost` are relayed? Could you elaborate on what `relay_hosts_only` meant to achieve here?

Comment: You state that outgoing SMTP is not a problem - is @tsc_chazz assessment wrong then? Is there any way to verify that only `localhost` is allowed to send emails on behalf of mailboxes at my domain?

Comment: Outgoing is not a problem when it's not an open relay (other servers than only the server itself to send mail using smtp). Don't use localhost by the way, that can be misused. To verify that your server is not a open relay you could use this https://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx. Or check the logs /var/log. You could also search the logs with `grep "Relaying denied" /var/log/maillog`, If you find such entries, it indicates that your server is configured to reject unauthorized relaying. If you don't then you need to review your config

Comment: With `FEATURE(relay_hosts_only')` allows you to specify which servers are allowed to relay, to prevent open relay. You do need to specify which hosts are allowed to relay that's not included in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP Server in not wide open, unless the Ubuntu maintainers have meddled with the configuration.

You can fine tune this in /etc/mail/access

```
# Allow a local NAS to send mail
192.168.1.200  RELAY
# Deny a Bad Server
192.0.2.33 ERROR:550 We don't accept mail from you
```

The spoofing of an IP-Address With TCP the spoofing of an IP-Address is very hard.
I Have not seen this used by any spammer.

Be aware that you don't trust Reverse-DNS to allow relaying.

For reference there is an operator manual named op.ps and or op.txt included in "sendmail-doc" package.